# Visual Studio 6 Processor Pack compatibility

Tags: performance, intel, visual-c++-6, amd-processor, visual-studio-6

I've seen that a Processor Pack is available for Visual Studio 6, however it appears to only be available for users with SP5 and I am already using SP6:

*In addition, the Visual C++ Processor Pack (VCPP) was removed from Service Pack 6. If you have the VCPP installed, installing SP6 will remove it from your machine. If you wish to continue using the VCPP, you will need to stay with SP5 or migrate to Visual Studio 2002 or 2003 (recommended).*

Firstly, is this processor pack compatible with Visual Studio 6 SP6?

Secondly, would it actually help me?  I'm concerned about getting the most from my application, but it needs to run on all flavours of Intel and AMD chips so I can't just target one platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the clue was in the question:

In addition, the Visual C++ Processor Pack (VCPP) was removed from Service Pack 6. If you have the VCPP installed, installing SP6 will remove it from your machine. If you wish to continue using the VCPP, you will need to stay with SP5 or migrate to Visual Studio 2002 or 2003 (recommended).

I'm going to upgrade to a newer Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4):

Rebuilding a system, i just had this problem, and found this Microsoft KB Article (872907): [**You receive an "ERROR: This version of Processor Pack will only...**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/872907) It's for VB, but i'm assuming it applies to VC++ as well. It seems to have installed okay. Once i get everything set up and compiling, hopefully it really did install okay.

**Solution:** Modify the `latest` registry key at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\6.0\ServicePacks` to be **5** instead of **6**.

Processor Pack install stops complaining.

Comment: In x64 versions of windows, the key is actually at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\6.0

Comment: Interesting, swine. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

I think the processor pack is already integrated with SP6, like the [following document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2005/aa718349.aspx) says.

Comment: I think the original plan was to include the processor pack in SP6, but it never happened.